# Object serializer

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, serialization

I have this little utility/helper which serializes a form into a javaScript object.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(fn) {
  var o = {},
      a = this.serializeArray(),
      that;
  $.each(a, function() {
    that = this;
      if($.isFunction(fn)){
        that = fn(that.name, that.value);
      }
    if(o[this.name] !== undefined) {
      val = that.value || '';
      if(!o[that.name].push) {
        o[that.name] = [o[that.name]];
      }
      o[that.name].push(that.value);
    } else {
      o[that.name] = that.value;
    }
  });
  return o;
};
```

A typical usage of this plugin will be:

```
someNameSpace = {
    //... 
    processForm: function (form) {
        return JSON.stringify(form.serializeObject(function (key, val) {
            return {
                name: key,
                value: encodeURIComponent(val)
            };
        }));
    }
    //...
};
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this piece of code?

- Maybe improve performance
- Maybe its the API-Design
- Code readability..

See [original gist](https://gist.github.com/adardesign/5091258#file-jquery-serializeobject-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm barely even sure what's going on here:

```
if(o[this.name] !== undefined) {
  val = that.value || '';
  if(!o[that.name].push) {
    o[that.name] = [o[that.name]];
  }
  o[that.name].push(that.value);
} else {
  o[that.name] = that.value;
}
```

All the `this`/`that` is pretty confusing to look at, especially with all the square brackets mixed in. More descriptive names would help immensely.

But also, you check for `o[this.name]` but then you define `o[that.name]`. So if my `fn` function makes all the names identical, it won't work. For instance, if I have 3 inputs (a = 1, b = 2, and c = 3) in a form, and I supply a `fn` like so:

```
$(form).serializeObject(function (name, value) {
  return {
    name: "x",
    value: value
  };
});
```

I get:

```
{ "x": 3 }
```

instead of the expected `x: [1, 2, 3]`

It'd be much easier to just let me manipulate the objects directly. You wouldn't have any this/that to bother with, and I could simplify my `fn` to

```
$(form).serializeObject(function (object) {
  object.name = "x";
});
```

No need to build and return a new object.

Other things I noticed:

- Don't use `... === undefined`. Unfortunately, `undefined` is not a reserved word, meaning that `undefined` *can be defined* in some JS runtimes. So if somewhere, some joker has written `undefined = 23;` it'll break your code. Use `typeof x === 'undefined'` instead.
- Don't use jQuery to do a simple loop. A `for` loop works quite well, with less overhead and no context-switching.
- Don't use jQuery just to check it something's function. Use `typeof x === 'function'` instead.
- Don't use `x.push` to check if something's an array. Use `x instanceof Array`. For all you know, `x.push` could mean anything. (User [winner-joiner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22820/winner-joiner) adds: watch out for frame/iframe situations [where `instanceof` doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473273/why-are-myarray-instanceof-array-and-myarray-constructor-array-both-false-wh))
- You have a `val` variable which is 1) not used, 2) not declared (thus implicitly global!), and 3) if it were used, it'd mess up. I my `fn` returns a value of, say, `false` on purpose, it'd become an empty string, because `false || '' => ''`. Don't do anything clever with the values; especially not *after* the user's `fn` may have changed them. Assume the values are correct, regardless of what they are.

And again: Use descriptive variable names. It took me quite a while to figure out your code.

I'd write it like this:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function (decorator) {
  var source = this.serializeArray(),
      serialized = {},
      i, l, object;

  for( i = 0, l = source.length ; i < l ; i++ ) {
    object = source[i];

    if( typeof decorator === 'function' ) {
      decorator(object);
    }

    if( serialized.hasOwnProperty(object.name) ) {
      if( !(serialized[object.name] instanceof Array) ) {
        serialized[object.name] = [ serialized[object.name] ];
      }
      serialized[object.name].push(object.value);
    } else {
      serialized[object.name] = object.value;
    }
  }
  return serialized;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! really helpful! I will update the gist according to your recommendations and would you mind to please take a second look at it?